# Fullscreen video in the Chrome webview

Tags: flash, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webview, html5-video

I have a problem with webview tag in the Google Chrome Extensions. When I open some video on youtube and press "Full-screen" button it behaves differently depends on the video type.

1. If video displays using video tag
   (`<webview src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zk0TpSX0tKE"></webview>`), it opens video in full
   webview and markdown breaks.
2. If video displays using flash player
       (`<webview src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Vcgdl4xQ18"></webview>`), it opens in
       full-screen and works fine.

Is there any way to make a video tag full-screen feature works in the same way like flash player?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if comes to any help for the others:
Since the HTML5 video gets fullscreened inside the webview, one can set the webview width and height to the screen width and height so that the video fills the whole screen. This can be done as:

```
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function(){
  if (chrome.app.window.current().isFullscreen()){
    webview.style.height = screen.height + 'px';
    webview.style.width = screen.width + 'px';
  }
  else{
    /*get webview to original dimensions*/
  };
});
```